# What do we know about the future of this character?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

In *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, we discover that

> Qi'ra has a connection to Crimson Dawn, which turns out to be led by Darth Maul. He tells her to join him, and implies cryptically they'll be working much more closely together in the future.

Is this in reference to something we've seen take place already (in *Star Wars: Rebels* for example), or to something we don't yet know?

More specifically, has any of the production team or actors stated whether or not this character will be returning in some fashion, or was this in reference to something already existing in canon?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maul associating with the galatic underworld is a continuation of his plot-thread from *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, where he forms and leads [the Shadow Collective](http://starwars.wikia./wiki/Shadow_Collective), an alliance of several criminal organizations, including the Pyke Syndicate seen in the film. The name "Crimson Dawn" is likely a reference to Black Sun, another criminal institution that comprised part of the Shadow Collective.

Maul tells Qi'ra to come to [Dathomir](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dathomir), Maul's homeworld and a planet that has featured heavily in both Legends and the new EU, including *The Clone Wars* and *Rebels*.

Maul is still a major player in the underworld in *Solo*, while he was disposed in *Rebels*, placing both *Solo* and his future encounter with Qi'ra before the series.

Said encounter has not been shown yet. It may occur in one of the [possible *Solo* sequels](https://www.google.com/amp/s/screenrant.com/alden-ehrenreich-han-solo-sequels-contract/amp/) or in a separate work in the *Star Wars* franchise.

Comment: Was not aware of *possible Solo sequels* at the time, so this does answer my question, which was essentially trying to understand the direction the ending was taking with those characters. Didn't know if it was meant to lead into something that had already happened in Rebels, or something we don't know about yet that will come up in future movies.